# Vue + Vite + Rollup: Dynamic import not working on production build

Tags: vue.js, es6-modules, rollup, rollupjs, vite

I'm trying to use Vite with ***dynamic-import*** Vue SFCs, but it does not work on production build.

There is stackblitz example:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-ant1g2?file=src/main.ts

Test command and localhost:3000 shows good.

```
vite
```

However preview and localhost:4173 shows blank.

```
vite build && vite preview
```

What is wrong? Do you have any solutions?

Comment: JS apps usually do not just "show blank" without any error in console. Check the dev tools....

Comment: I can confirm this behaviour and there is no error message on the console. I guess it is about the path `./App.vue`. It is not resolved as an asset, which is needed for production. Did you check out `https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/html-and-static-assets.html#static-assets-handling?

Comment: I forgot to mention that there are no clues in the console.
I am not very familiar with Vite and Rollup so I don't know how to apply @Nechoj
 's link.

Comment: Why do you want dynamic loading of `App.vue` and not standard import?

Comment: More info: I added console.log and found that create cycle of App.vue does't run.

Comment: @Nechoj Guys on stackoverflow say so all the time. I am asking why it fails in such a simple use case.
And in my product, almost all of dynamic import of SFCs fails--that is, if dynamic import really doesn't work, then I need to give up using dynamic import in the whole product.

Comment: I do not recommend using dynamic component import. See also docs: https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/application.html#the-root-component

Comment: So there is no way to make the rollup understand dynamic imports?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `defineAsyncComponent`.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-pmqny3?file=src/main.ts

```
import { createApp, defineAsyncComponent } from 'vue';

console.log('start app');
createApp(defineAsyncComponent(() => import('./App.vue'))).mount('#app');
```

Thanks for https://misskey.dev/notes/8zjl4hnyz5

Comment: This does not seem to work with dynamic imports

Comment: This would not work If we don't know what we exactly have to import (for e.g. App.vue)  What If the App.vue part is dynamic?

Comment: @ShakilAlam Exactly. I am facing the same issue. Please check my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75988909/vue-3-dynamic-import-issue/75988945

Answer (score 2):

I was recently doing a PoC and was surprised to know that `dynamic` imports feature works fine in `dev` mode but fails in production build without a special configuration. Reason behind this (probably) is that `vite` uses `esbuild` as  bundler for `dev` mode while using `rollup` as bundler for `production` build.

Due to this discrepancy in the behavior between two modes, I am making sure that I always test a new concept in both `dev` and `production` modes to make sure it works in `production` build too otherwise you will end up developing a feature in `dev` mode only to realize at a later stage that it is not working in `production` mode.

You will need to list all the dynamic imports under `rollupOptions` of `vite.configs.ts` file in order to make it work in `production` mode -

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'

export default defineConfig({
    build: {
        rollupOptions: {
            external: [
                "/path/to/external/module.es.js"
            ]
        }
    }
})
```